# plot a piecewise regression

Tags: piecewise

Can someone help me with plotting a piecewise linear regression?

```
data = sales_ID
I have a plot with a sales-curve:
x-axis: time
y-axix: sales
```

Now I d'like to create unique regressionlines for three pieces on the sales-curve.
The Breakpoints should be `sales=100000` and `sales=250000`.
I tried `abline(lm(sales_ID$sales~sales_ID$time))`, but how can I split this regressionline into the required pieces?

Thanks a lot for your help!
Tanja